# calling the js function while loading the page in ibm mobiefirst multiapp

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

i am trying to develop a multipage app where i will be able to load many page but my task is to when loading page #2 i need the page2 **function hello** to run.

when clicking on func "change" i am able to load page2 but i need to run function "hello".

main.js

```
var pagesHistory = [];
var currentPage = {};
var path = "";
var busyIndicator = null;


function wlCommonInit(){
    busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator();

    // Special case for Windows Phone 8 only.
    if (WL.Client.getEnvironment() == WL.Environment.WINDOWS_PHONE_8) {
        path = "/www/default/";
    }

    $("#pageload").load(path + "pages/page1.html", function(){
        $.getScript(path + "js/page1.js", function() {
            if (currentPage.init) {
                currentPage.init();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>demo</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <!--
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
            -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;">
            <div id="pageload">
            </div>

            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
            <script src="jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

page1.js

```
currentPage = {};

currentPage.init = function(){
WL.Logger.debug("Page1 :: init");

};
function funchange()
{
    $("#pageload").load(path + "pages/page2.html");
}
```

page1.html

```
<script>
    $.getScript(path + "js/page1.js");
</script>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="funcchange();">
```

Page2.js

```
currentPage = {};

currentPage.init = function(){
    WL.Logger.debug("Page2 :: init");

};
function hello()
{
    alert("hello");
}
```

page2.html

```
<script>
    $.getScript(path + "js/page2.js");
</script>
```

Comment: How is this different from the sample application? This is what it is doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a function in main.js:

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    ...
    ...
}

function test() {
    alert ("test");
}
```

Then in Page2.js, simply call `test();`.

Comment: my situation is to when loading the 2nd page i need to load 2page js function that is run the 2 page js functionhello when onloaditself